# send email async work in localhost but not in server

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to send email, it work well in localhost but when I upload it to sever then it doesnt work, and report nothing.
here is my code:

EmailHelper.cs

```
private const string SMTPHost = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    private const string FromAdress = "no-reply@abc.com";
    private const string FromDisplay = "abc.com";
    private static readonly MailAddress From;

    static EmailHelper()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(FromAdress, FromDisplay);
    }

    public static void Send(string to, string cc, string subject, string body, List<Attachment> attachments, bool isHtml)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage { Subject = subject, Body = body, IsBodyHtml = isHtml };
        message.From = From;
        message.To.Add(to);
        if (cc != null)
        {
            message.CC.Add(cc);
        }
        if (attachments != null)
        {
            attachments.ForEach(attachemet => message.Attachments.Add(attachemet));
        }

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTPHost);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@abc.com", "abc123");
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.SendCompleted += delegate(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = sender as SmtpClient;
            if (smtpClient != null)
            {
                smtpClient.Dispose();
            }
        };
            client.SendAsync(message, null);
    }
```

here is email content

```
EmailHelper.Send(email, null, "", emailBody, null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

Localhost Port:- `client.Port = 25;`

Server Port:-      `client.Port = 587;`